# Mongodb setting unique field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
 TENANT
  { "_ID" : 11, NAME : "ruben", OPERATION :[{OPERATION_ID: 100, NAME : "Check"}] }
```

how to set the OPERATION_ID has unique to avoid duplicate values and to avoid null values like primary key?

Answer (score 12):

When you want the OPERATION_IDs to be unique for all tenants, then you can do it like that:

```
db.tenants.ensureIndex( { operation.OPERATION_ID : 1 }, { unique:true, sparse:true } );
```

When you want the OPERATION_IDs to be unique per tenant, so that two tenants can both have the operation_ID:100 but no tenant can have operation_id:100 twice, you have to add the _id of the tenant to the index so that any given combination of _id and operation_id is unique.

```
db.tenants.ensureIndex( { _id: 1, operation.OPERATION_ID : 1 }, { unique:true, sparse:true } );
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding a [unique index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-unique:true) on OPERATION.OPERATION_ID will ensure that no two distinct documents will contain an element in OPERATION with the same OPERATION_ID.

If you want to prevent a single document from having two elements in OPERATION with the same OPERATION_ID, you can't use unique indexes; you will have to use set update operators (such as $set and $addToSet).  You could turn OPERATION into a subdocument keyed by OPERATION_ID, like so:

```
{ "_ID" : 11, NAME : "ruben", OPERATION : {"100" : {NAME : "Check"} }}
```

Then you can enforce uniqueness by issuing updates with $set; for example:

```
db.<collection>.update({NAME: "ruben"}, {$set: {"OPERATION.100.NAME": "Uncheck"}})
```

Regarding null values: MongoDB doesn't feature non-null constraints on fields (it doesn't even force a given field to have a single type), so you will have to ensure in your application that null values aren't inserted.

Comment: hi want to insert values but having a unique name ,like username for logging in , how to make username unique while inserting into a login collection