# How to set index on document in sub-array (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to set a unique index on a field within a subarray of a collection in MongoDB. This index will also be set to drop existing dupes. I'm following the MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/), but it does not seem to be working (dupes still exist in my db). I believe my issue may be how I'm attempting to access the document within the 'photos' sub-array. Below is my schema and the code I'm trying to use to set the index:

```
{
    event: String,
    headline: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    date: String,
    start: String,
    end: String,
    dateState: String,
    radius: String,
    team_1: String,
    team_2: String,
    object_id: String,
    longitude: String,
    latitude: String,
    cover: {
        img: String,
        username: String
    },
    photos: [{
        img: String,
        link: String,
        username: String,
        profile: String,
        text: String,
        longitude: String,
        latitude: String,
        created_time: String
    }]
}

gameday.events.ensureIndex( {"photos.img": 1}, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )
```

Comment: A unique index on a sub-doc field within an array prevents dups between docs but not within them.  Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I'm seeing. I'm trying to prevent dupes within that 'photos' subarray.

Comment: See the second part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921700/mongoose-unique-values-in-nested-array-of-objects/15926031#15926031