# Mongoose: get the size of an array of objects with aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, size, aggregate

I have a document in my collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b8aaaebf57de10e080c9151"),
"user_email" : "temp@temp.com",
"platforms_budget" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8aaaebf57de10e080c9154"),
        "platform_id" : "f_01",
        "platform_name" : "Facebook"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8aaaebf57de10e080c9153"),
        "platform_id" : "i_01",
        "platform_name" : "Instagram"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8aaaebf57de10e080c9152"),
        "platform_id" : "f_02",
        "platform_name" : "Facebook_Adds"

    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

I want to find specific user by "user_email" and get the length of the relevant "platform_budget" array. Which in this case suppose to be length=3.

My function is like this:

```
var BudgetSchema = require('../models/Budget');

  router.post('/temp', async function (req, res) {
  var length = await BudgetSchema.aggregate(
    [{ $match: { user_email: "test@test.com" } }, { $unwind: "$platforms_budget" },
    { $project: { "platforms_budget.count": { $size: '$platforms_budget' } } }])

  console.log(length);
})
```

When I try to console.log(length) I get an empty array.

I saw other answers on stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447670/mongoose-get-length-of-array-in-model), but I still can't understand what am I doing wrong or how to extract the size from the responce.

How do I get "platforms_budget" array size?
Thank you.

Comment: Remove `$unwind` stage will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `../models/Budget` exports a [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Model), the [Model#aggregate(Array, Function)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) expects the pipeline with aggregations as an array and an optional callback function that is passed an error (if any) and the result (if any).

```
.aggregate([...], function(error, resource) {
    // do what you want here
});
```

Or what you can also do is use the `Aggregate` object itself and invoke `.exec(Function)` on it where the function is a callback as well.

```
.aggregate([...]).exec(function(error, resource) {
    // do what you want here
});
```

I personally am still a bit confused [about the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) of `.aggregate(Array, Function)`.

> If a callback is passed, the aggregate is executed and a Promise is returned. If a callback is not passed, the aggregate itself is returned.

It sounds like if a callback is passed a promise is still returned but I couldn't find any evidence of any promise being returned by `.aggregate(Array, Function)` [on GitHub at all](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L3264).