# Is there a way to make values in an array of a document unique to the document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this (simplified) schema:

```
{
  name: {type:String, unique: true}
  idList: [String]
}
```

I would like values in `idList` to be unique in the whole collection

I have looked at `mongoose-unique-array` and but it seems to only support unique values only within the array.

Do I need to to make the `idList` another collection and link it back with id?

Comment: Please Check [Mongo schema, array of string with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788688/mongo-schema-array-of-string-with-unique-values)

Comment: I am looking to have the value be unique across other arrays in entries in the document too, beyond just the array itself.