# Mongodb mongoose - How to add a document to an array if not present by a field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Document like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162a"), 
    "devicesCxt" : [
        {
            "deviceId" : "1232", 
            "userAgent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0", 
            "online" : false, 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162c"), 
            "loginAt" : ISODate("2019-10-28T03:21:22.178+0000")
        }
    ], 
}
```

I want to add this

```
{
    "deviceId" : "1233", 
    "userAgent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0", 
    "online" : false, 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162b"), 
    "loginAt" : ISODate("2019-10-28T03:21:22.178+0000")
}
```

I want something like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162a"), 
    "devicesCxt" : [
        {
            "deviceId" : "1232", 
            "userAgent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0", 
            "online" : false, 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162c"), 
            "loginAt" : ISODate("2019-10-28T03:21:22.178+0000")
        },
        {
            "deviceId" : "1233", 
            "userAgent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0", 
            "online" : false, 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162b"), 
            "loginAt" : ISODate("2019-10-28T03:21:22.178+0000")
        }
    ],
}
```

if `deviceId: 1232` not allow，else `deviceId: 1233` can succeed.

**Can't have the same object for deviceId**

`deviceId` should be kept unique in the array.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you tried this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose

Comment: Thank you Jayakumar Thangavel，That's not what I wanted，I want the deviceId not to repeat

Comment: You could try creating a [`unique index`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on the deviceId field.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to determine if a deviceId exists when adding

Comment: @Amorous If I understand correctly you want to update/add new incoming object to `devicesCxt` array if it doesn't contain an object with same `deviceId`.. correct?

Comment: yes, devicesCxt does not contain the same deviceId object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could have a conditional update query to prevent addition of document to **`devicesCxt`** array field when the **`deviceId`** of incoming object already present. [**`$push`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

**Mongo Query:**

```
const incomingDoc = {
  deviceId: "1233",
  userAgent: "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0",
  online: false,
  _id: ObjectId("5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162b"),
  loginAt: ISODate("2019-10-28T03:21:22.178+0000")
};

db.collection.update(
  {
    _id: idToFilterIfAny,
    "devicesCxt.deviceId": { $ne: incomingDoc.deviceId }
  },
  { $push: { devicesCxt: incomingDoc } }
);
```

Comment: @Amorous See if this is what you require. Where the basic idea is filter on a field to update which adds a document when the `deviceId` is not present.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I need，Thank you so much @ambianBeing,I don't want change my schema,This is the best way for me. Thanks again

Comment: Excuse me, If there is an execution modification, other cases are added.How can i do?

Comment: @Amorous Would suggest to ask a new self contained question with all the new cases added which helps to get better visibility and help from others at SO, and point me to the link of it, I ll check it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601090/mongoose-array-of-objects-if-there-is-an-execution-modification-other-cases-sh

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Your schema could be something like this:

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
  deviceCtx: [{
      deviceId : { type: String, unique: true},
      userAgent : { type: String, },
      online : { type: Boolean, },
      loginAt : { type: Date, },
    }]
});
```

To add new item in the array:

```
const mySchema = await mySchema.find({ _id: "5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162a" });

const newDeviceId = req.body.deviceId;
mySchema.devicesCxt.push({
  deviceId : newDeviceId,
  userAgent : "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0",
  online : false,
  loginAt : new Date()
});

await mySchema.save();
```

Comment: @Amorous do you want your `deviceId` to auto increment?

Comment: Then the code above should work. Since, deviceId is set to `unique`.

Comment: Let me try, Thanks again @Dijkstra ，Different documents allow the same deviceId to exist，But only one in the same array

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
let deviceid = {
    "deviceId" : "1233", 
    "userAgent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0", 
    "online" : false, 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db65eb2a2f3a61fe88e162b"), 
    "loginAt" : ISODate("2019-10-28T03:21:22.178+0000")
}
myModel.update(

    { $push: { devicesCxt: deviceid } },
);
```

but if you want to mongo add _id to your array you need to define it in your schema

Comment: Hi，babak abadkheir，Thanks for your answer.Does mongoose have a way to determine if deviceId exists before it can be saved? If not, I can only modify my schema

Comment: @Amorous check this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-array and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574427/5677187