# How to obtain object id and also how to update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to obtain the object id for any article already in db so that I can validate that the article exists before comments are made.

The issue is on the router (/blog/article/comment). I cannot get the article object id from /blog/article/:postid. I want to pass this id to articleId like this:

```
articleId: req.params.postid
```

I have also tried:

```
articleId: req.article._id
```

***model structure: comment.js***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: { type: String },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  articleId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Article' },
  dateCommented: { type: Date, default : Date.now }
});
```

***Article model: article.js***

```
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
  commentId:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Comment'},
  title: String,
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  blog: [{
    topic: { type: String, unique: false, lowercase: true },
    body: {  type: String, unique: false, lowercase: true },
    tags: [ 'first', 'mongodb', 'express'],
    created: Date,
    modified: { type : Date, default : Date.now },
    state: {  type: String, unique: false, lowercase: true }
    }]
});
```

***main.js***

```
router.param('postid', function(req, res, next, id) {
  if (id.length !=24) return next(new Error ('The post id is not having the correct length'));
    //articleId: req.param('postid'),
  Article.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id)}, function(err, article) {
    if (err) return next(new Error('Make sure you provided correct post id'));
    req.article = article;
    next();
  });
});

router.get('/blog/article/:postid', function (req, res, next) {
  Article.findById({ _id: req.params.postid }, function (err, article) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.render('main/publishedArticle', {
      article: article
    });
  });
});


router.post('/blog/article/comment', function(req, res, next) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      var comment = new Comment({
        articleId: req.params.postid,
        content: req.body.content,
        user: req.user._id
      });

        comment.save(function(err) {
          if (err) return next (err);
          req.flash('success', 'Thank you for your comment');
          callback(err, comment);
        });
    },
    function(comment) {
      Article.update({_id : comment.articleId }, { $set: { commentId: {} }}, function(err, updated) {
        if (updated) {
          res.redirect('/')
        }
      });
    }
  ]);

});
```

*Another issue I have is how to update the commentId for each comment in the Article*

```
Article.update({_id : comment.articleId }, { $set: { commentId: {} }}, function(err, updated)
```

Comment: For the second question, do you want to add a bunch of comment IDs to the article? Is that what your asking how todo?

Comment: Yes, I want each comment id to be saved to the article that is commented on

Comment: See my answer for the additions I added. It should get you off to the right start. :)

Comment: Thanks @Treeless, this did not save the article id from article model to articleId. Is there something I am missing? I need the article object id (_id) that is stored in mongodb to be saved as articleId in the comment

Comment: My code is incorrect I think. comment is an array is it not? If so, comment[0].articleId should be what you need.

Comment: Treeless,  the articleId from red.body.articleId is not grabbing the article id (_id)  from Mongo db or the postid. So comment.articleId is empty in DB. That's my first issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135481/discussion-between-treeless-and-codi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `/blog/article/comment` route is a post request. Just submit your articleId in the body of that request. You'll have to send it up from the client. You can access it with `req.body.articleID` (If that is what you call the variable).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js) for more info on POST requests in node.

For your second question:

Within your article schema you have commentId, That is a single record. What you want is an array of comments. Something like this:

```
comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Comment'}]
```

Then within your code...

```
...
function(comment) {
  //comment should contain all the comments 

  //Grab the article
  Article.findOne({ _id: comment.articleId}, function(err, article){

    //Go through all the comments in 'comment' compare them with the ones in artcle.comments.
      //The ones that aren't already in the article object get put into newComments...
    var newComments = [];

    Article.update({ _id: comment.articleId }, { $addToSet: { comments: newComments } }, function(err, updated) {
    if (updated) {
      res.redirect('/')
    }
  });
  });
}
...
```

I didn't fully implement the code, but it should get you off to the right start.

[addToSet Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)
[Some more examples of add to set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921700/mongoose-unique-values-in-nested-array-of-objects)