# Push or addToSet for multiple items in subdocument in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**Is it possible to use Push or addToSet for multiple items**, for example this code add's one note if it doesn't exist yet, in a subdocument array for user. But what if I have 200 notes?

```
const note = { id: 1 };
User.update(
    {name: 'admin', 'notes.id': {$ne: note.id}}, 
    {$push: {notes: note}},
    function(err, numAffected) { ... });
```

Is it okay to use a foreach loop and run this code 200 times?

Comment: It is ok but slow. That said, I am not aware of a "MongoDB way" of doing that in a nicer fashion. What I'd recommend is simply reading the document, modifying it on the client and then sending the whole thing to the database in a single udpate.

Comment: But then I miss the whole point of the Mongoose validation right?

Comment: Which validation exactly? The update will go through Mongoose again so there should be no difference?

Comment: So you would validate if a note.id is unique on the client side then? Since Mongoose has that unique validator, which I can add in my NoteSchema..

Comment: You mean this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-array? My understanding - I am not a Mongoose user - is that this will happen upon a save/update so it should work. Just try it out!

Comment: @dnickless to add to your recommendation, the reading, modifying and sending should all happen within a transaction session since otherwise it losses the atomic function of update