# How to restrict DUPLICATE EMAILS insert in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to insert a record into the DB as bulk upload. When the email already exists it should not insert, but it is inserting. Can anyone please suggest me help?

```
data.forEach(function (v, i) {
    ` async.waterfall([
                function (done) {console.log(filterjson)
                  Student.find(filterjson).exec(function (err, students) {
                    if (err) {
                      return res.status(400).send({message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)});
                    } else { console.log('success'+students)
                      if (students && students.length > 0) {
                        console.log('fail')
                        writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv'))
                        writer.write({FirstName: student.first_name,LastName: student.last_name, email: student.email, mobile: student.mobile, error:'Email already exists'});
                        res.jsonp({ 'errorCode': common.statusCodes.COMMON, 'respMessage': 'Email already exists' });
                     } else {
                        done();
                      }
                    }
                  });
                },
                function (done) {
                  student.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                      return res.status(400).send({message:errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)});
                    } else {


                      done();
                    }
                  });
                },
           }
```

Comment: might be a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395118/mongodb-setting-unique-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add constraints for that column

> Example
>
> `db.student.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } )`

Ref. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Note:  Need to delete if there is any duplicate data, other wise you will get E11000 duplicate key error collection: ...

Comment: make sure you switched to correct database.

use <dbName>;

db.<collection_name>.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true} );

you need to delete if there is any duplicate data, other wise you will get E11000 duplicate key error collection:  ...